# Any way to have emacs shell pass the TAB into a readline command running inside it?

Tags: shell-mode

Eg. when you're running nice things like Perl or Ruby REPLs, you have code/command completion exposed via GNU Readline. What I want to do is set some elisp/env variable when entering/exiting such a program to indicate that I want `shell-mode` to pass the TAB key onto those programs.

Note that `C-q TAB` also does not work, so I think that Readline is also ignoring it because `TERM=dumb`, but setting it to eg. vt100 also doesn't do the trick, so it might even be looking at `EMACS=t`.

Comment: Comint doesn't work that way.  It waits for a line to be sent with `RET`, then receives output until it recognizes a prompt.  Completion must therefore be solved on its side.

Comment: Take a look at [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/), or [grass-mode](https://bitbucket.org/tws/grass-mode.el/wiki/Home) to see how completion is handled directly in elisp on the Emacs side, rather than by relying on readline.

Comment: This would be also useful to Prolog mode, where pressing tab is supposed to prompt the interpreter to generate next solution.

Comment: @Tyler the thing is where the knowledge exists elsewhere (eg. in a running interpreter). I guess I could make some sort of readline proxy that could have completion delegated to it from lisp - seems like a lot of work :)

Comment: @MarkAufflick ESS does something like that I think, with most completions provided via elisp, but some special cases/situations passed to the R process. The special cases can result in painfully slow completions.

Comment: The various `comint-send-*` functions allow you to send input to the process.  You could certainly write a command which would send the input you wanted, and bind that to TAB.  Whether you'd get back the output you want in a form that was usable is another question, but you might as well try it and see what happens.

Comment: python.el uses readline for completion when "native completion" is enabled, though this does require some setup on the python side. And it doesn't work on w32 (due to lack of pty).

Answer (score 2):

`M-x shell` works line-at-a-time.  It passes a line of input to the external shell process when you press `Ret` key.

`M-x term` passes every keystroke to the external shell process, with the exceptions of `C-c` and I think `Esc`.  When you press `Tab` it will be seen and interpreted by the external shell process.

Answer (score 2):

As @user20119 pointed out, `M-x term` might be a good option: it also supports dynamically switching to "line mode" which is somewhat similar to what you get with `M-x shell`.

`M-x eshell` also tries to give you a mix of the two behaviors.

I'll also point out that `C-q TAB` didn't work because all it does is to insert a TAB character in the buffer (rather than sending a TAB to the sub-process).  Furthermore, just sending a TAB char to the underlying process wouldn't be sufficient, because the text on the current line hasn't yet been sent to the process, so you might need something like:

```
(defun my-comint-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
         (str (buffer-substring (process-mark proc) (point))))
    (process-send-string proc (concat str "\t"))))
```

and indeed you'll probably also need to convince `M-x shell` to use a different setting for `$TERM`.